# Checksum fail on visual studio 2010 Trial RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The checksum of the iso is wrong (ultimate edition)
I'm getting 7790db7d2aac9e1ee8baa34d42988577689c9e7a
should be SHA-1: 0x8371f6a8d090063fcc320617e94854374633df3c

The strange thing is the download is in 4 rar files and rar does not report an error (internal checksum) so the corruption happend at microsoft and not during download.

Am I the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got `7790db7...` as well using cygwin's `sha1sum` utility. The software installed without any trouble.